# How to use a PostgreSQL or SQLite (preferred) database in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, database, sqlite

I searched a lot on the web but couldn't find an answer.
I'm creating a simple tech wiki/forum website and want to simply add a subscription service that would notify a group of people's emails if any updates are made.

Simplified: The user would enter his/her e-mail (no name only e-mail) in a JS, HTML form and that needs to be stored in a (preferred) SQLite .dd database from which the e-mails would be retrieved (manually) to be sent e-mails to.

Note: The database is currently empty with no tables in it.

Comment: The basic answer is that you create a server application to do the things you want done.

Comment: I'm not good at that so I need full details

Comment: You should at least try and then you are likely to get help.
This looks too much like you are trying to get someone to do your work for you.

Comment: @DaniDev btw I'm 14 years old so it's my own website not someone else's work

Comment: @Omer lets start with this:  "this is my own website" do you have a server or a hosting platform in place? if not?  start there, that is a start which will then dictate what technologies are available to you.  If so what is the technology stack i.e. webserver? Database server ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably too broad and not appropriate for the StackOverflow since an answer would entail the design of an entire system covering a number of different technologies including Databases, Website Construction, and Email (which itself is a special form of hell IMO for the uninitiated).

I would recommend you first line out exactly what functionality in detail your website will handle (can people make accounts? can arbitrary users make posts/page?) From there, you will need to divide those features into the right applicable technologies/concerns.

If you've haven't already, I would choose a set of technologies and look for tutorials covering the areas of concern. There are about a dime of dozen blog post on various websites covering common features across web applications. If you don't know what to pick, I would just go with what the blog post uses. Admittedly, this is a terrible suggestion, but I am assuming this is just a side project for you to learn and not for a paying client so that approach is fine to a certain degree (if this is for a paying client, well you're on your own).

Comment: And I'm not exactly looking for an answer but resources

Comment: I need to get resources on how to do that. I'm not looking for exact answers.  e.g. courses , languages easy to learn for server-side apps (for beginners), etc.

Comment: Okay, so first things first, a sufficiently broad and vaguely well defined google search should show more than plenty of tutorials and resources to build something close to what you want in X language. Above all else, the ability to effectively use a search engine to answer your own questions is a critical skill for a programmer of any form to develop. If you really have no idea of what languages to start with, I would recommend Python. There’s a good community behind it and contains fewer gotchas than other common web languages like JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: Second, as far as the features and working out requirements are concerned, think about implicitly what you’re asking for. Granted, this skill will come as you learn more about this subject. So let’s consider the feature where a user inputs their email into a form which is used to communicate with them over email. Think this through. It sounds awfully like a service that a user signs up for thats sends them notifications about a topic, no? You effectively have a high level requirement to create an account on your service, albeit with very limited need to store data.